# Pegar valor específico de um arquivo

Tags: c, c++, string, arquivo

Tenho o seguinte formato de arquivo:

```
username=teste1;
status=ONLINE;
username=teste2;
status=ONLINE;
username=teste3;
status=OFFLINE;
```

Onde uma das linhas representa o nome do usuário e a linha de baixo o status do usuário logo acima.

Gostaria de pesquisar por um username específico e mostrar o status dele, mas não consigo pensar em qual o problema por trás deste código.

Por enquanto tenho o seguinte código:

```
int isUserOnline(char *username) {

    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(FILE_NAME,"r");
    int i = 0;

    char line[MAX] = {'\0'};
    char destiny[MAX] = {'\0'};
    while(!feof(f)) {

        bzero(destiny, sizeof(destiny));

        fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
        valueAfterEquals(destiny, line);

        if(strcmp(destiny, username)) {
            bzero(destiny, sizeof(destiny));
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
            valueAfterEquals(destiny, line);
            printf("is: %s \n", destiny);
            if(strcmp(destiny, "OFFLINE")) {
                return 1;
            }
            else 
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Este acima deveria buscar o username e verificar se existe, se estiver offline, retorna um;

A função valueAfterEquals é está, simplesmente pega o valor depois do igual e concatena:

```
void valueAfterEquals(char * destiny, char * buffer){

    int k = 0;
    while(buffer[k] != '='){ 
        k++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    k++; //pular o '='
    while(buffer[k] != ';'){
        destiny[i] = buffer[k]; 
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A função strcmp() tem que ser igual a 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)

const char* FILE_NAME = "file1.txt";
const int MAX = 128;

void valueAfterEquals(char* destiny, char* buffer) {

    int k = 0;
    while (buffer[k] != '=') {
        k++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    k++; //pular o '='
    while (buffer[k] != ';') {
        destiny[i] = buffer[k];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}

int isUserOnline(const char* username) {

    FILE* f;

    fopen_s(&f, FILE_NAME, "r");

    char line[MAX] = { '\0' };
    char destiny[MAX] = { '\0' };
    while (!feof(f)) {

        bzero(destiny, sizeof(destiny));

        fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
        valueAfterEquals(destiny, line);
        if (strcmp(destiny, username) == 0) {
            printf("is: %s \n", destiny);
            bzero(destiny, sizeof(destiny));
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
            valueAfterEquals(destiny, line);
            if (strcmp(destiny, "OFFLINE") == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* username = "teste1";
    printf("%d\n", isUserOnline(username));
}
```